# how do i use DRF serializer to get the following api structure?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how can i use drf to get an api similar to:

```
{
    "user":{
        "username":"my username",
        "email":"my email"
    },
    "product":[
        {
            "id":id,
            "product_name":"somename",
            "type":"sometype",
            "date_bought":date,
            "image": "image address",...
        },
        {
            "id":id,
            "product_name":"somename",
            "type":"sometype",
            "date_bought":date,
            "image": "image address",...
        },....
    ]
}
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250 ,default='', blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product_image')
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    instock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    instock_qty = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_name}"

class UserHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    date_bought = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user},{self.product}'
```

i need to be a ble to do the following:

1. when GET , retrive the above data.
2. add products (user is read only, only the authenticated user will be able to add product).

how  do i write the serializer to achieve the above objectives

fairly new to django so notify me if i missed something

Comment: what is purpose of UserHistory model

Comment: it records the transaction between a user and the product they purchase. for eg user 1 has bought product 3 at datetime x.

Comment: Are you aiming to do 1 and 2 in the same GET request?

Comment: no 1 is get to get view the products history of the authenticated user and 2 is a post  to add sold products to the history